# Do jQuery's height() and width() methods maintain an image's proportionality?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, height

Google results and the jQuery documentation indicate that jQuery's height() and width() methods make no effort to maintain an element's proportionality.

Yet when I run my code, it appears as if proportionality is indeed maintained.

Can anyone set the record straight?

Here's my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').gallery();
     });

   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" alt="" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

jquery.gallery.js

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.gallery = function() {  
    return this.each(function() {
        var e = $(this);
        e.height(128);
    });
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery does indeed do nothing to maintain the proportions of the image. If you set only the width or only the height of an image, it will automatically maintain it's proportions.

Answer (score 2):

If you set only the height of an image, the width is adjusted in proportion and vice versa. Proportionality is not maintained if you set both of them.

Comment: But jQuery doesn't do that. It's how the image element works by itself.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of writing that down, but indeed, that behaviour is that of the image itself. Doen't matter for the answer, though.